# Using JavaScript's Intl object to display country names with a definite article

Tags: javascript, internationalization, intl

In some languages a country name can have a definite article, like for example [German](https://learngerman.dw.com/en/location-names-with-an-article/l-38047077/gr-38313110) and I saw [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28177/city-names-with-articles), that some of the places in English as well.

So my question would (an I'm not sure whether it's possible or not) **whether JavaScript's built-in Intl package would have a functionality to display country names with a definite article** by providing an option and what option might it be? (I've searched a lot, but unfortunately couldn't find anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the answer is no.

There are no article country names in JS

Otherwise we would see The Netherlands and The Falkland Islands

```js
const regionNamesInEnglish = new Intl.DisplayNames(['en'], { type: 'region' });
console.log(regionNamesInEnglish.of('NL'));
console.log(regionNamesInEnglish.of('FK'));
```

There are not that many anyway

https://www.engvid.com/english-resource/the-with-country-names-lakes-rivers/

- The Bahamas
- The Cayman Islands
- The Central African Republic
- The Channel Islands
- The Comoros
- The Czech Republic
- The Dominican Republic
- The Falkland Islands
- The Gambia
- The Isle of Man
- The Ivory Coast
- The Leeward Islands
- The Maldives (The Maldive Islands)
- The Marshall Islands
- The Netherlands
- The Netherlands Antilles
- The Philippines
- The Solomon Islands
- The Turks and Caicos Islands
- The United Arab Emirates
- The United Kingdom (of Great Britain and Northern Ireland)
- The United States (of America)
- The Virgin Islands

Comment: thank you, unfortunately I couldn't find anything so far.